# adding blank rows to a blank java table?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have here a code and I am quite confused on how to make this thing work. the purpose of the program is to show the current inventory list that we have. I want it to be automatically added to my table. how can I do that?

my erroneous line is

```
                    String[] itemize = { s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s0 };
                //invTable.addRow(itemize);
```

I also included my code just in case someone needs to test it. thanks!

```
    invTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
    invTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {{null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}},
        new String [] {
            "Item", "Code", "Weight", "Doctor", "Supplier", "Department", "Cost", "Price", "Quantity", "Threshold"
        }
    ));
```

I think the problem lies in the code above.

I finally made it work thanks to the help of people in this site. i just removed the code above.

```
 private void insertRows() throws SQLException, Exception{
        modelx = new DefaultTableModel();
        modelx.addColumn("Name");
        modelx.addColumn("ID");
        modelx.addColumn("Weight");
        modelx.addColumn("Doctor");
        modelx.addColumn("Supplier");
        modelx.addColumn("Department");
        modelx.addColumn("Cost");
        modelx.addColumn("Price");
        modelx.addColumn("Quantity");
        modelx.addColumn("Threshold");
                                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");

                database = "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\\floresClinic.accdb;";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(database, "", "");
        s = conn.createStatement();
                rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM medItem ");
                 int cou = 0;
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                                  s1 = rs.getString("productName");
                                  s2 = rs.getString("productID");
                                  s3 = rs.getString("productWeight");
                                  s4 = rs.getString("doctor");
                                  s5 = rs.getString("sName");
                                  s6 = rs.getString("department");
                                  s7 = rs.getString("unitCost");
                                  s8 = rs.getString("unitPrice");
                                  s9 = rs.getString("quantity");
                                  s0 = rs.getString("threshold");
                                  if(!s2.equals("Select?")){
                                  modelx.insertRow(0, new Object [] {s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s0});
                                  //String[] itemize ={s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s5,s7,s8,s9,s0};
                                  //System.out.println(s1+s2);
                                  //modelx.addRow(itemize);  

                                  }
                            cou++;
                    }  

    }
```

my only problem now is that it is shown backwards. the first row contains the last row of my database table.

Comment: Try adding the row to the TableModel directly instead of the JTable...

Comment: You shouldn't be extracting values as String, as unitCost, unitPrice, quantity, threshold all look numerical in nature to me

Comment: Also the naming semantics of the method `insertRow()` implies that the method should just insert one row at a time. I don't think a new table and table model should be created each time you add a row. Unless I'm wrong about the method name. Just a thought.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow/mcve) (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example).  328 LOC is not 'minimal'.

Comment: add the row to the table model and then set the model to the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's a problem. When You drag and drop the table, everything involved with the process of initializing the table and adding the table to the container, is handled inside the `intComponents` method. So, in your case, a new `JTable` is added.

But in your `insertRow` you make `invTable` a new instance of `JTable` by doing

```
invTable = new JTable(model);
```

So what is ultimately happening is that in the constructor, `initComponens()` is called, which initialized and adds the original table. But then `insertRow()` is called which makes `invTable` a completely different instance.

So what you should do instead, is just take out the `invTable = new JTable(model);`. You can create a new `DefaultTableModel` that's fine. I would actually recommend it (as calls to `addRow()` of the model will cause repaint, which is inefficient) in this case. After all the rows are added to the new model, then call `invTable.setModel(model);`

---

> "my only problem now is that it is shown backwards. the first row contains the last row of my database table"

Here is your problem

```
modelx.insertRow(0, ....)
                 ^
                 |
```

You keep inserting the to the 0th row which will push all the previous added rows down, hence the *"backwardness"*. You probably want to use `insertRow(cou, ....)`.. But that is unnecessary. Just use `modelx.addRow(...);`

Answer (score 0):

```
 invTable = new JTable();
 invTable.setModel(modelx) 

// you CAN'T SKIP .setColumnIdentifiers() or your rows won't show up              
   modelx.setColumnIdentifiers("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5","col6","col7","col8","col9","col0");
```

Then You add those rows using DefaultTableModel's reference by calling .addRow( ) method..

```
while(rs.next()){
    ............
    ............

    modelx.addRow(new Object[]{s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s5,s7,s8,s9,s0});

}
```

- It's hard for me to test your code because i don't have that kind of database, but my                                     solution   should  work !

Comment: there is no error now @Fev, it just doesn't show rows on my form. I think its working and there is something i missed.

Comment: @Daniel, try to change this line  invTable = new JTable(modelx); TO  invTable = new JTable(); THEN invTable.setModel(modelx) . And see if it works.